# Is there a way to only extract parts from a font file?

Tags: fonts, webpage

Here I have font file that I use and embed in a webpage, but it is quite a big font because it is a CJK font and contains CJK characters. I only want the A-z 0-9 and symbols part.

Is there any tool that can let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

### in Microsoft word there is a option to embed only the fonts in your document.

left click on your html file click "open with…", Microsoft word, (if you dont see it clik the down arrow, then Microsoft word,) office, options, save, embed only fonts in document (not exact wording), apply/okay,then save.